# How do I select a set of data restricted by data that is not part of the set?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a simple table structure representing a many-to-many relationship between **Images** and **Tags**. The *FooID* columns are `uniqueidentifier`s (GUIDs). *Name* and *Path* are `nvarchar`s.

[image: Table schema]

I have a set of tags and need to select a single image to display next to each one. The image should be the first one sorted by Path, that is `MIN(Path)`.

I've been able to do this so far by executing a single SELECT statement for each TagID.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Images.ImageID
FROM Images 
     inner join ImageTags on Images.ImageID = ImageTags.ImageID 
     inner join Tags on ImageTags.TagID = Tags.TagID 
WHERE Tags.TagID = @p0 
ORDER BY Images.Path
```

This leaves me wondering, though: **Is there a better way?** Can I fetch this data all at once by passing in a whole *set* of TagIDs? The result set should have one row for each TagID provided, as long as there is at least one image with that tag applied to it.

```
SELECT ImageID, TagID
/* ... ??? ... */
WHERE TagID IN (@p0, @p1, @p3, ...)
```

Comment: You could put the desired tags into a temporary table and join on that...

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  IT.ImageID,
            IT.TagID,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY IT.TagID
                                    ORDER BY I.Path)
    FROM ImageTags IT
    INNER JOIN Images I
        ON IT.ImageID = I.ImageID
)
SELECT  T.TagID,
        C.ImageID
FROM Tags T
INNER JOIN CTE C
    ON T.TagID = C.TagID
WHERE C.RN = 1
AND TagID IN (@p0, @p1, @p3, ...)
```